# How To Post a Model Containing Array into The Retrofit Body Post?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Please help me in making the the retrofit interface as for this kind of `Body` parameter :

```
{
    "filter": {
            "category_id": [1, 2],
            "state": ["kuala lumpur", "selangor"]
    },
    "sort": {
        "type": "state",
        "value": "ASC"
    }
}
```

So currently this is my retrofit interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("universities-filter-sort")
suspend fun getUniversitiesFilterSort(
    @Field("filter") filter: Filters.Filter,
    @Field("sort") sort: Filters.Sort
): Call<University>
```

and this is my body model class as for the parameter

```
data class Filters(
        @SerializedName("filter")
        val filter: Filter,
        @SerializedName("sort")
        val sort: Sort
    ) {
        data class Filter(
            @SerializedName("category_id")
            val categoryId: List<Int>,
            @SerializedName("state")
            val state: List<String>
        )
    
        data class Sort(
            @SerializedName("type")
            val type: String,
            @SerializedName("value")
            val value: String
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the body of the `POST` method is defined by `@Body` annotation in the retrofit. Try to use `@Body` like the following and in calling the `getUniversitiesFilterSort` function, pass an instance of your `Filters` class as the argument.

```
interface UniversitiesApi {

    @POST("universities-filter-sort")
    suspend fun getUniversitiesFilterSort(
        @Body args: Filters
    ): Call<University>
}
```

Comment: Heyy thanks for the answer. Anyway I have tried those "@FieldMap", "@Body", and all, and the main problem is because I added "@FormUrlEncoded". And now it successfully gave the output according to Okhttp.

Comment: You're welcome :) I've omitted it on the answer, but forgot to mention that you should do it also :)

Comment: My pleasure :'D !